# What does Shih Dao name and tiles mean?

Tags: meaning

Once upon a time there was a logical game [Shih Dao](https://www.classicdosgames.com/game/Shih_Dao.html) - I liked it and got curious: what does the game title mean and what are the signs on tiles? Unfortunately, game help doesn't say a word about it.

[image: Game screen]

There are six different signs used, by browsing Chinese signs lists I managed to identify [中](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD) and [大](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7) but failed to find the other four. As I have no idea about Chinese alphabet, I think of them as "house" (several ones in top-right of the screen), "zigzag" (one purple in top-right), "dancer" (several in the center) and "basket" (four in bottom-right), which probably has nothing to do with their actual meanings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the link you provided already shown the answer:

> shih dao is a clone of ishido: the way of stones

so shih dao is 石 (stone) 道 (way)

the six characters on the tiles are:

大 - big

中 - middle

小 - small

春 - spring

由 -cause

東 - east

have fun :)